# Find and replace custom tags in html

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, placeholder, markup

Im using placeholder plugin in CKEditor 4

This plugin create some HTML/Markup like below

```
[[class="related-document-content" data-document="70062" data-title="Forening vil komme private brøndejere til undsætning"]]
```

Our current platform uses a div for the same module like:

```
<div class="related-document-content" data-document="70062">Forening vil komme private br&oslash;ndejere til unds&aelig;tning</div>
```

When showing the HTML to users i let JQuery traverse the document using

```
  $('.related-document-content').each(function....)
```

Is there any way to accomplish the same using the first markup ?

Comment: Jquery works with the current state of DOM structure, so does the first string exists in the current tree?

Comment: Yes the code is rendered as is means when viewing the html you can see the text

    [[class="related-document-content" data-document="70062" data-title="Forening vil komme private brøndejere til undsætning"]]